# Recursively convert "" to false in object using underscore

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I'm trying to convert all `""` values to `false` using underscore and it's not working. Is there a simpler way?

```
var _ = require("underscore");

var test = {
    "one": "",
    "two": "",
    "three": {
        "four": ""
    },
    "five": "this string is intact"
};
```

first attempt, messes up objects

```
function z(object){ 
    return _.map(object, function(value, key, list){
        if(_.isObject(value)){
            return z(value);
        }else{
            var ret = {};
            ret[key] = (value == "") ? false : value;
            return ret;
        }
    });
}
```

second attempt failed

```
var _false = function(object){
    var nb = {};
    var _false = function _false(object, parent){
        _.each(object, function(value, key, list){
            if(_.isObject(value)){
                nb[key] = {};
                return _false(value, key);
            }else{
                nb[parent] = (value == "") ? false : value;
            }
        });
    }(object);
    return nb;
}
```

Comment: @Pointy That doesn't matter to me.

Comment: (I removed my off-target comments.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to modify your objects, you have to go ahead and do it!

```
function z(object){ 
    _.each(object, function(value, key){
        if(_.isObject(value)){
            z(value);
        }else{
            object[key] = (value === "") ? false : value;
        }
    });
}
```

That modifies your object directly, not creating a new object.

The problem with `_.map()` is that it always returns an **array**. If you want to end up with an object, like the original, you can't use it.

Comment: I disagree https://gist.github.com/reggi/5303810 that it can't be a `new` object. I agree that I can't use `map()`.

Comment: @ThomasReggi yes you're right - the "map" issue didn't click for me at first :-)

Answer (score 1):

Why do need to use underscore? This is probably easier with plain JS for/in.

http://jsfiddle.net/dSZbe/

```
// Accepts an object to convert '' -> false
var falsify = function(obj) {

    // for each key in the object
    for (var key in obj) {

        // store the value for this key in a local variable
        var value = obj[key];

        // if the value is an empty string
        if (value === '') {

            // update the object, change the value of this key to false
            obj[key] = false;

        // Value is not empty string.
        // So is it an object?
        } else if (typeof value === 'object') {

            // It IS an object! that means we need to do all this again!
            // This is what makes this recursive
            falsify(value);
        }
    }

    // return the modified object, though the object passed
    return obj;
};


// test data
var test = {
    "one": "",
    "two": "",
    "three": {
        "four": ""
    },
    "five": "this string is intact"
};

// proof it works, all empty strings are now `false`.
alert(JSON.stringify(falsify(test)));
```

---

But lastly, be sure you need to do this... `""` is a falsy value in JavaScript.  Which means that:

```
var emptyString = "";
if (emptyString) {
  // never gonna happen
} else {
  // always gonna happen
}
```

So if you simply want to write code like `if (test.one) { ... }` then you don't need to do this at all.